# How to Convert JpaRepository result to my custom DTO class

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, java-8

I want to convert page to page

so I implemented like this

```
@GetMapping("/history")
public Page<ResponseAllHistoryDto> getAllHistory() {
    Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(0, 20, Sort.by("createdAt"));
    Page<History> histories = historyRepository.findAll(pageable);
    return histories.map(history -> {
       return ResponseAllHistoryDto.builder()
               .history(history)
               .tags(tagRepository.findByHistoryHistoryId(history.getHistoryId()))
               .auths(authRepository.findByHistoryHistoryId(history.getHistoryId()))
               .build();
    });
}
```

Sadly. It give me

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class com.wrapsody.demo.ResponseAllHistoryDto and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: org.springframework.data.domain.PageImpl["content"]->java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList[0])
```

what is the problem....:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `DTO` class needs to have a default constructor, getters and setters. Try to annotate it with lombok's `@Data`.